# Run Time Error 13 - Mismatch on Date

Tags: vba, excel

avid reader, first time poster here. I have a Macro that I obtained from the internet for the most part, then made some adjustments. It's purpose is to color code cells that have passed a certain duration. It was working fine earlier, but now I am getting an error on it for a "Type Mismatch". The line that reads "This is where the error is" is where I am getting the mismatch. I am puzzled because it was working fine earlier. I am not a seasoned programmer by any means, but I just try to troubleshoot things. I have looked all over the net and cant find a specific answer to my question.

In addition, if any of you are willing, I would appreciate your advice on how to make this code run ONLY at startup of the workbook and NOT periodically as it is set up to do so now.This code is not placed in a worksheet, but in a Module.I mention this because I am not sure how much of a practical difference it can make any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
 Public TimeToRun As Date

Sub Auto_Open()
Call ScheduleCompareTime
  End Sub

Sub ScheduleCompareTime()
TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CompareTimeStamp"
  End Sub

Sub CompareTimeStamp()
Dim rgTimeStamp As Range
Dim rdTimeStamp As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim MyNow As Date
Dim TimeStamp As Date, TimeStampp As Date

Set rgTimeStamp = Range("c1:c500")
Set rdTimeStamp = Range("H1:h500")

For i = 1 To rgTimeStamp.Rows.Count

    If Not rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1) < 1 Then 'don't run for an empty cell

        MyNow = CDate(Now - TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)) 'time instantly
        TimeStamp = CDate(rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1)) 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS!!
        If TimeStamp < MyNow Then 'if it's old at all
            rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'make fill colour red
        End If
    End If

  Next

For j = 1 To rdTimeStamp.Rows.Count

    If Not rdTimeStamp.Cells(j, 1) < 1 Then

        MyNow = CDate(Now - TimeSerial(0, 0, 0))
        TimeStampp = CDate(rdTimeStamp.Cells(j, 1))
        If TimeStampp < MyNow Then
            rdTimeStamp.Cells(j, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If


    End If 'closes If Not
Next
Call ScheduleCompareTime  'begins the scheduler again
End Sub

Sub auto_close() 'turn the scheduler off so you can close workbook
Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "CompareTimeStamp", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: There probably is a mismatch, e.g. there's a header now in `C1` so say `CDate("Time stamp")` is in fact supposed to give an error. There could be more subtle chages too: having an invalidly formatted date or a single space in a cell. To check these take a look at the `i`'s value when it halts into debug.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have data in one or more cells that Excel cannot convert to a date.  You can get around this by adding some simple checking such as this:

```
'.... beginning of your code

If Not rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1) < 1 Then 'don't run for an empty cell

    MyNow = CDate(Now - TimeSerial(0, 0, 0)) 'time instantly

    If IsDate(rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1)) = False Then
        MsgBox "Invalid date found in cell " & rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1).Address(False, False)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    TimeStamp = CDate(rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1)) 'THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS!!
    If TimeStamp < MyNow Then 'if it's old at all
        rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'make fill colour red
    End If
End If


'... rest of your code
```

If you only want the code to run at startup then change Sub Auto_Open to this:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
Call CompareTimeStamp
End Sub
```

Comment: Also comment out the recurring `Call ScheduleCompareTime  'begins the scheduler again`.

Comment: And if that doesn't cut it I would test `IsNumeric(rgTimeStamp.Cells(i, 1).Value2)`. A `Double` type value can be converted to a date while not being one. In itself a text can be valid too of course...

Comment: Ahhh, thank you both for opening my eyes! I believe the error I was having was because I kept mingling with the timestamp cells (clearing them, deleting them) and thus they were changing values. Thanks for the heads up! I will still test the solutions you provided to get a better understanding of different ways to troubleshoot.Do either of you, by chance, know how to FREEZE the timestamp so it doesnt adjust after any change in the target cell?